# How do I make it so my page view controller isn't endless?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a page view controller that allows me to scroll through the various signup pages and enter the necessary information. The problem is it just scrolls in a circle. How do I make it so that the PlayerInfo page is the last page I can scroll to?

```
lazy var SignupArray : [UIViewController] = {
    return [self.VCInstance(name: "ParkSelect"),
            self.VCInstance(name: "SportSelect"),
            self.VCInstance(name: "PlayerInfo")]
}()

private func VCInstance(name: String) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self

    if let firstVC = SignupArray.first {
        setViewControllers([firstVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}

public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
    guard let viewControllerIndex = SignupArray.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
        return SignupArray.last
    }

    guard SignupArray.count > previousIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return SignupArray[previousIndex]
}

public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
    guard let viewControllerIndex = SignupArray.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1

    guard nextIndex < SignupArray.count else {
        return SignupArray.first
    }

    guard SignupArray.count > nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return SignupArray[nextIndex]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
    guard let viewControllerIndex = SignupArray.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
        return nil
    }

    return SignupArray[previousIndex]
}


public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
    guard let viewControllerIndex = SignupArray.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1

    guard SignupArray.count > nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return SignupArray[nextIndex]
}
```

The reason it is endless because

when previousIndex becomes zero you pass the last VC in array

```
guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
    return SignupArray.last
}
```

when nextIndex is equal to count of signUp array u pass the first VC in array.

```
guard nextIndex < SignupArray.count else {
    return SignupArray.first
}
```

Remove these two code and ur PageViewer will stop

Comment: Mind telling me what you changed or added?

Comment: @Alexander : Was typing explanation posted code first thats all

Comment: Now the pages don't scroll at all.

Comment: removing those two lines of code will still yield the same result of my pages not scrolling.

Comment: @Alexander : Please use the code I have posted one of ur condition in viewControllerBefore was wrong because of which its not scrolling

Comment: @Alexander : Am glad I could be of help :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Return `nil` instead of wrapping around. For example:

```
public func pageViewController(_ pvc: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter vc: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
    guard
        let i = SignupArray.index(of: vc),
        i < SignupArray.count - 1
    else {
        return nil
    }
    return SignupArray[i + 1]
}
```

or, even more concisely:

```
public func pageViewController(_ pvc: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter vc: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
    let i = 1 + (SignupArray.index(of: vc) ?? SignupArray.count)
    return i < SignupArray.count ? SignupArray[i] : nil
}
```